# Accessing iPhone playback data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to be able to pull out the user's 50 most recently played songs, then be able to sort that via artist/album/genre etc. How can I make this happen immediately upon the app's opening and what would be the best way (I'm thinking dictionary?) to bundle this up so I can send it to a server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008211) might be what you're looking for. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083117/is-it-possible-to-access-iphone-ipod-touch-music-stats-through-the-sdk) for how to access the various media item properties.

Your app delegate's `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method would be an appropriate place to scan on-launch, and an NSDictionary converted to JSON should be suitable serialization format.

Be sure to inform the user before sending their data off to your server, however.

Comment: So you couldn't filter the results from a query by play time, even though this is an option in iTunes?